# Check if an array is stack-sortable

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, stack

Here is the question:

We want to rearrange a sorted array [1, ..., N] using a stack.

Ex:

```
 * push 1 then pop 1.
 * push 2 then push 3 then pop twice and get 3 then 2.
```

Then we can get [1,3,2] from [1,2,3]

Check if we can get the given array by rearranging the sorted array (ascending order) using a stack.

Limitation:

```
 * 0 < The size of the given array (N) <= 100,000
 * 1 <= The items of the given array <= N
 * No duplicates inside the given array
```

Test cases:

```
 * [1, 3, 2]: true
 * [3,1,2]: false
```

I wanted to know what I am missing from the code below. The following code fails on some test cases:

```js
function solution(array) {
  const stack = [];
  let idx = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
    if (i !== array[idx]) {
      stack.push(i);
    } else {
      idx++;
    }
  }

  for (idx; idx < array.length; idx++) {
    let item = stack.pop();
    if (item !== array[idx]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What tests cases exactly are you failing on? Also, could you explain what the logic is that you're running in your code?

Comment: You've got two loops. The first loop only pushes, and the second loop only pops. What you need is one loop that pushes and pops. Test case that demonstrates this: [2,1,4,3].

Comment: @user3386109 you are 100% right. Yes, I was missing that case. Hats off to your knowledge. I will keep learning to catch these mistakses.

Comment: @shapiroyaacov

Test cases I was failing on were the followings:
[3, 2, 5, 4,1]
[2,1,4,3].

 My logic was to simply push to stack if the given array index + 1 does not match with the given array's corresponding value. Then compare the stack with the rest of the given array's items while doing pop.

 I was able to get help.

 But again, thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is not correct, as already mentioned in the comments, you cannot just push and then pop.

The easiest way is to always push if the number is not matching and if it is a match then pop as many values as possible:

```js
function solution(array) {
    const stack = []
    let idx = 0
    for (let i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
        if (i != array[idx]) {
           stack.push(i)
        } else {
           idx++
           while (stack.length > 0 && stack[stack.length - 1] == array[idx]) {
               idx++
               stack.pop()
           }
        }
    }
    return idx == array.length
}

console.log(solution([1,3,2]))
console.log(solution([3,1,2]))
```